# 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ClientID' and no extension method 'ClientID'

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ClientID' and no extension method 'ClientID' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
$('.close-modal').click(function (e) {
    $('.modal, .modal-backdrop').fadeOut('fast');
    //Storing Id of the grids in an array
    var gridId = ["GridMyMeeting", "GridAllMeeting", "GridMyMeeting"];

    //Using setTimeout in for loop to rebind grid data at the same time
    for (var i = 0; i < gridId.length; i++) {
        window.setTimeout($find("<% =" + gridId[i]+ ".ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().rebind(), 10);
    }
});
```

Comment: You seem confused about the difference between your client and server-side code. `grid[i]` is a JS variable so you cannot concatenate it in a block of C# code. Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to rebind three radgrid at a time,once the popup window is closed.but only one radgrid is  rebinding. I want to bind all the three grid, My code is here

Comment: *$('.close-modal').click(function (e) {
                    $('.modal, .modal-backdrop').fadeOut('fast');
                    var mymeeting = $find("<% =GridMyMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                    var allmeeting = $find("<% =GridAllMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                    var activemeeting = $find("<% =GridMyMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                    mymeeting.rebind();
                    allmeeting.rebind();
                    activemeeting.rebind();
                });*

Comment: *function rebind()
            {
                $find("<% =GridMyMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().rebind();
                $find("<% =GridAllMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().rebind();
                $find("<% =GridMyMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().rebind();
            }*

Answer (score 0):

You should create the array of `ClientID`, then you can directly use `gridId[i]`

```
var gridId = ["<% = GridMyMeeting.ClientID %>", "<% = GridAllMeeting.ClientID %>"];

for (var i = 0; i < gridId.length; i++) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $find(gridId[i]).get_masterTableView().rebind();
    }, 10);
}
```